# Can on-device sqlite database of a mobile app be updated without updating the the app at the app store?

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, android-sqlite

I am not an app programmer. I am planning an online e-commerce marketplace app and will be outsourcing the job. I have some programming knowledge and have few questions regarding the design of the app.

I want the app to be fast. so I am willing to store the information on the device using sqlite database, at the cost of space.

After the app is released, there will be new sellers and new product categories.  I wish to know if I can update the sqlite database only on the device without actually updating the app at the store?

Comment: Yes. Just need some kind of web based API that the app retrieves the updated info from and then caches to the device.

Comment: Caches or updates the database?

Comment: Same thing really, in this instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to connect your app to a webservice from where retrieve the info, and then the app logic must update the database.

One implementation could be: every time your app starts, it asks to the webservice "hey, do i need to update my database?" and then get the new data.